# Installing nuclide on Atom

Tags: node.js, atom-editor

I am trying to install nuclide on Atom but I am getting the follwong error. When I run

`apm install nuclide`

```
Installing “nuclide@0.125.0” failed.Hide output…

npm WARN engine nuclide@0.125.0: wanted: {"atom":">=1.5.3","node":">=4.1.1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.40","npm":"2.13.3"})
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/ammathu/Downloads/Atom 2.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/bin/node" "/Users/ammathu/Downloads/Atom 2.app/Contents/Resources/app/apm/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "/Users/ammathu/.atom/.apm/.apmrc" "--userconfig" "/Users/ammathu/.atom/.apmrc" "install" "/private/var/folders/sk/rxnvp2hs2nd0xp3w_bsq3f1d6b3pqf/T/d-116222-56925-dimbjc/package.tgz" "--target=0.34.5" "--arch=x64"
npm ERR! node v0.10.40
npm ERR! npm  v2.13.3

npm ERR! version not found: relative-date@1.1.2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/sk/rxnvp2hs2nd0xp3w_bsq3f1d6b3pqf/T/apm-install-dir-116222-56925-votedf/npm-debug.log
```

Any idea how to fix it?
`node -v` gives me   v5.0.0`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been able to install it from source:

http://nuclide.io/docs/advanced-topics/building-from-source/#linux__building

Run the following commands to build Nuclide from source.

```
# Clone the source
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/nuclide.git
$ cd nuclide
# Install dependencies
$ npm install
# Link the 'nuclide' package to Atom's package directory
$ apm link
```

Verify the installation by:

```
Open Atom.
Go to Atom | Preferences.
Click on Packages.
Verify nuclide as one of the packages.
```

Comment: the nuclide linked to atom. it shows in package list. but every time error is thrown  `Failed to load the nuclide package  can not find module 'bla bla bla'  the error was thrown from the nuclide package.`   can you please suggest something. Atom : 1.34.0 x64 and nuclide : 0.390.0 . nuclide added to atom like shown above.

Answer (score 5):

This solved it for me.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/nuclide.git
$ cd nuclide
# Install dependencies
$ yarn --pure-lockfile
# Link the 'nuclide' package to Atom's package directory
# You could also use apm link --dev ... see Development Mode below.
$ apm link
```

The npm install did not install all the modules necessary. Kept giving me errors, could not find module-... 
This is given in the their docs.
https://nuclide.io/docs/advanced-topics/building-from-source/#linux__building

Comment: This works for me. Thanks